# AWS Elastic BeanStalk Error writing to |/usr/sbin/rotatelogs

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS beanstalk app that after a reboot runs pretty smoothly for few hours, then all of the sudden the latency starts creeping up.

[image]

When I check the logs, I find a lot of these messages

> [log_config:warn] [pid 15905] (32)Broken pipe: [client 172.31.5.163:31780] AH00646: Error writing to |/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/healthd/application.log.%Y-%m-%d-%H 3600

I also read [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-and-lamp-issue-warning-mysqli_real_connect-hy000-2002)

It says if the logs get bigger than 10mb, server could get slow. Not sure if this applies to my case?
I couldn't figure out how to fix this and unfortunately I am not an AWS pro. Any assistance/ guidance on how to solve this issue would be great!